# Problem with spacedesk when running an UE5.3 application

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

I have a project inside Unreal 5.3 that uses MultiWindowsUE plugin, which allows me to have more than one screen rendering the game. When I play the game in a PC with two monitors, all goes fine, no problem, the two windows appears normally. But when I play the game using a PC with one monitor and one tablet connected via spacedesk, I have to click anywhere into the tablet screen to game open properly, otherwise, the two windows of my game stays on the monitor screen (not one in monitor and one in tablet). Anyone knows how to fix it or maybe what can possibly be causing it? Please someone help me!

In case my problem doesn't get resolved, I'm thinking of make a .bat file that automatically makes the click on screen, but I'm new in programming and don't know how to do that either. Hope anyone can help me!